# R: Looping while some parameters are static and some come from vectors

Tags: r, loops

I would like to create something like a loop, where I get a vector with two elements. The first element should be the result of the function when the first element of vec_a and vec_b are inserted into the function:

`example_function(parameter1 = vec_a[1], parameter2 = var_x, parameter3 = vec_b[1], parameter4 = var_y)`

and the second element should be the result of this:

`example_function(parameter1 = vec_a[2], parameter2 = var_x, parameter3 = vec_b[2], parameter4 = var_y)`

Where those are the inputs:

`vec_a <- c(1.01,1.42)`

`vec_b <- c(2.11, 1.99)`

`var_x <- 2`

`var_y <- 53.97`

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Look at the  `?Vectorize` function. You can vectorize over whatever parameters you like. It would be easier to be more specific if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that could actually be run. Many functions in R might do this already.

Comment: Consider mapply: `mapply(example_function, vec_a, var_x, vec_b, var_y)`

Comment: thank you Parfait! The mapply function worked like a charm.